# Limitação de 1000 valores no POWER BI

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

Fiz uma query na qual e uma view para jogar dentro do power bi e me trazer todos os dados, porém quando vou fazer a transformação desses dados para ficar organizado ele me limita em 1000 linhas, teria alguma forma de tirar essa limitação? E acontece de limitar dentro da aplicação também ?[limitação](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay5HV.png)
**query viewer feita completa no SQL e puxando os dados corretos porém dentro do power bi que ocorre o problema.**

Comment: Você já fez esta pergunta. Siga [as orientações já dadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/569994/o-limite-de-1000-valores-foi-atingido-power-bi#comment1003395_569994) para melhor aproveitamento do site. Para evitar duplicação de orientações, o espaço de comentários daqui foi desativado, mas você pode restaurar sua pergunta original e editar caso entenda que pode elaborar melhor dentro do escopo do site.